# Changing mocked service value only applies after another "it"

Tags: javascript, angular, testing

I've setup a test to a simple component with ngFor.
Here's the template:

```
<section #menuItem
           *ngFor="let tab of tabs">
    <h2>{{tab.name}}</h2>
    <div class="settings-card">
      {{tab.content}}
    </div>
  </section>
```

In my component, tabs is set as follows:

```
public get tabs() {
   return this.settingsMenuDataService.menuListItems.filter(item => item.show);
}
```

In my spec file I mock the service:

```
const SettingsMenuDataServiceMock = {
  menuListItems: []
 }
};

{ provide: SettingsMenuDataService, useValue: SettingsMenuDataServiceMock},
```

Now in my `it` I do like this:

```
it('', () => {
  SettingsMenuDataServiceMock.menuListItems = [
    {
      show: true
    },
    {
      show: false
    },
    {
      show: true
    }
  ];

fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SettingsComponent);
component = fixture.componentInstance;

fixture.detectChanges();

const nSections = fixture.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('section').length;
expect(nSections).toEqual(SettingsMenuDataServiceMock.menuListItems.length - 1);
});
```

What I get in `nSections` is 0, because at the time of the component's creation `SettingsMenuDataServiceMock.menuListItems` is empty.

If I add the changes in an `it` before the one above, it works:

```
it('', () => {
  SettingsMenuDataServiceMock.menuListItems = [
    {
      show: true
    },
    {
      show: false
    },
    {
      show: true
    }
  ];
});

it('should not add a section to the DOM if its hide property is false', () => {
  fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SettingsComponent);
  component = fixture.componentInstance;
  fixture.detectChanges();
  const nSections = fixture.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('section').length;
  console.log(nSections);
  expect(nSections).toEqual(SettingsMenuDataServiceMock.menuListItems.length - 1);
});
```

In this case the test pass.
My question is: why does it work between `it`s and how to make it work inside the relevant `it`.

Answer (score 0):

It is working if you split it in two its because the beforeEach is run after you change the property of `SettingsMenuDataServiceMock`. You can not change properties of somthing you provide after you provided it.

You could change your testsetup to something like this:

```
const menuListItems = [];

class SettingsMenuDataServiceMock {
  get menuListItems() {
    return menuListItems;
  }
}

...

{ provide: SettingsMenuDataService, useClass: SettingsMenuDataServiceMock }

...

it('', () => {
  menuListItems = [
    {
      show: true
    },
    {
      show: false
    },
    {
      show: true
    }
  ];

  fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SettingsComponent);
  component = fixture.componentInstance;

  fixture.detectChanges();

  const nSections = fixture.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('section').length;
  expect(nSections).toEqual(SettingsMenuDataServiceMock.menuListItems.length - 1);
});
```